# WebSQL access in Electron application

Tags: node.js, electron, web-sql

I have an Electron application running a Node Express server. The Electron main process is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function() {
   /* I want to use WebSQL here */
   res.send('Hi !!!');
});

app.listen(3636, function() {
   console.log('Listen ...');
});

var window = new BrowserWindow();
window.loadURL('http://localhost:3636');
```

I want to use WebSQL inside my Node Express controllers but, i tried with `openDatabase` command and obviouslly i received "undefined function" error.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get undefined function is that you're trying `openDatabase` in node and not in the browser. If you still really want to use websql but in node you can try out https://github.com/nolanlawson/node-websql#readme (`npm install websql -S` to add it to your `package.json`)